# default form in Symfony - add new input and change choice

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

my schema.yml :

```
User:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    username:
      type: string(255)
    password:
      type: string(255)
  attributes:
    export: all
    validate: true

Group:
  tableName: group_table
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    name:
      type: string(255)
  relations:
    Users:
      foreignAlias: Groups
      class: User
      refClass: GroupUser

GroupUser:
  columns:
    group_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
  relations:
    Group:
      foreignAlias: GroupUsers
    User:
      foreignAlias: GroupUsers
additional:
  columns:
    id:
      type: integer(4)
      autoincrement: true
      primary: true
    new:
      type: string(255)
  attributes:
    export: all
    validate: true
```

i generated new module:

> php symfony doctrine:generate-module
>   --with-show --non-verbose-templates frontend user User

and i have form add user:

http://localhost/user/new

image: http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/7726/znew.png

i would like add for this form input **new** from the module **additional** and change the sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice for multiple checkbox. 
how can i make it?

THX!

Comment: This question and your previous one indicate that your missing fundamental Symfony knowledge. Go through the [Jobeet Tutorial](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_2/). It will save you from many mistakes and save you time in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice** has an option called 'expanded' that if it's on true then will display the options with checkboxes (check [this example from the symfony's Jobeet](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/10#chapter_10_sub_customizing_the_job_form)).

In your UserForm.class.php you have to put something like this (check your BaseUserForm.class.php)

```
<!-- lib/form/doctrine/UserForm.class.php -->
...
public function configure(){

    $this->setWidget('groups_list', new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array(
              'multiple' => true, 
              'model' => 'Group', //check that on your base
              'expanded' => true, //set checkboxs
    )));

}
...
```